# How to display array key only if it wasn't already displayed

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

I am trying to make a journal type application. Since I want it sorted by date, I put the date that I'm pulling, as the key and then the text as the value in an array. What I'm trying to do is just display a date once, even if there are two matching keys.

so in the example below it would ideally return:

```
1/2/2013
   entry 1
   entry 2

1/5/2013
   this is another day
```

From this input:

```
   $array = array('1/2/2013'=>'entry 1', '1/2/2013'=>'entry 2', 
'1/5/2013'=>'this is another day');

    //loop through array and echo the date and value, but only echo date if havent already
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That array structure is not possible in PHP because array keys are unique. After assigning the variable you'll notice the array has only two elements, not three, because the second entry overwrites the first.

If you can order the entries by date first, consider something like:

```
<?php

$posts = array(
    array('date' => '1/2/2013', 'title' =>'entry 1'),
    array('date' => '1/2/2013', 'title' =>'entry 2'),
    array('date' => '1/5/2013', 'title' =>'entry 3'),
);

$date = '';
foreach ($posts as $p) {
    if ($date != $p['date']) {
        echo 'Date: ' . $p['date'] . "<br/>";
        $date = $p['date'];
    }
    echo 'Title: ' . $p['title'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware keys have to be unique identifiers, you may however be able to unset and create a new array with that as the key so you can have multiple data in that ie

```
Array
0
Date1 => string
1
Date2 => array("string 1","string2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could allow for multiple events on the same day by creating a multidimensional array. Such as:

```
$events = array(
  '01/01/2010' => array(
    'event1', 'event2'
  ),
  '02/02/2011' => array(
    'event3', 'event5'
  )
);
```

After this you should be able to loop over the array for each event:

```
foreach($events as $date => $data) {
  echo $date .' - '. implode(',', $data);
}
```

Comment: @zod - Perhaps a question for the op, although quote: `I put the date that Im pulling, as the key and then the text as the value in an array` sounds like it can be

Answer (score 0):

use

array_key_exists

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

or use two loops and use array_unique

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php